# ios - mixing midi files, each with own sound font

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, midi, coremidi

I'm looking for a way to mix 2 or more midi files, each with their own sound font files. I've found the following code for one file and tried to do multiple music players but i guess that shouldn't be the right approach. Also i get some weird pop sound every second.

So is there any other way, maybe without the musicplayer and musicsequence methods, using only au units?

Here's the code i found in another thread:

```
-(void) playMusic:(NSString*) name
{
NSString *presetURLPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GortsMiniPianoJ1" ofType:@"SF2"];
NSURL * presetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:presetURLPath]; 
[self loadFromDLSOrSoundFont: (NSURL *)presetURL withPatch: (int)3];

NSString *midiFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mid"];
NSURL * midiFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:midiFilePath];

NewMusicPlayer(&musicPlayer);

if (NewMusicSequence(&musicSequence) != noErr) 
{
    [NSException raise:@"play" format:@"Can't create MusicSequence"];  
}

if(MusicSequenceFileLoad(musicSequence, (CFURLRef)midiFileURL, 0, 0 != noErr)) 
{
    [NSException raise:@"play" format:@"Can't load MusicSequence"];
}

MusicPlayerSetSequence(musicPlayer, musicSequence);
MusicSequenceSetAUGraph(musicSequence, _processingGraph);
MusicPlayerPreroll(musicPlayer);
MusicPlayerStart(musicPlayer);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple MusicPlayer instances sounds a bit awkward (to keep in sync) and I have doubts that multiple AUGraphs would work. I haven't tried it myself.

One approach using a sole instance of `MusicPlayer` would be to load the tracks from each midi file into a 'master' sequence. You can assign an AUSampler node (with unique soundFont) to each track (`MusicTrackSetDestNode`) and connect them all through an `AUMixer`. You would need to manage the tempos from each midi file (using `MusicTrackNewExtendedTempoEvent`) to assign file tempos to the relevant tracks. Muting tracks + track volume is easily handled at the track or mixer level.

I guess much depends on the nature of the midi files you are working with. Fwiw - I did lots of research on midi file playback on iOS and there is nothing out there that is as easy to use as MusicPlayer. However, the [Bass lib](http://www.un4seen.com/) might be worth looking at if MusicPlayer turns out not to work for you.

**Specifying the number of mixer inputs:**

```
// set the bus count
UInt32 numBuses = BUS_COUNT; // a constant defined elsewhere
result = AudioUnitSetProperty(mixerUnit, 
                              kAudioUnitProperty_ElementCount, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                              0, 
                              &numBuses, 
                              sizeof(numBuses));

if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"Error setting Bus Count" withStatus: result]; return;}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. I had that idea too and started to code it like that, but then I thought i could assign soundfonts only to MusiqSequences and not MusicTracks and so i gave up that approach.

Comment: I've achieved the multi track muting approach you suggested - and it works well for one use case. But is there a way to force the multiple players to sync - could a midi clock help here? I want to change the play head on the tracks autonomously / start and stop. Is it impossible to build out the midi mixing parts of an app like abelton live in core audio / audio toolbox?

Comment: When I try to set up multiple AUSampler nodes with the mixer, I can't adjust the volume individually. Even though they're connected to separate input busses, (verified with CAShow,) the volume of bus 0 controls the volume of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue as you. All tracks play with the first sound font instrument. I followed your solution but it not work at first. Finally, I resolve the problem. As your mentioned, the sequence of calling functions really maters. Yes, it is. Actually, the sequence calling should be like this:

```
.....
MusicSequenceSetAUGraph(s, _processingGraph);
.......
MusicTrackSetDestNode(track[i], samplerNodes[i]);
......
[self loadFromDLSOrSoundFont];
......
MusicPlayerStart(p);
```

This works in my project.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried setting the nodes for each track, but that didn't change anything. The soundfont gets only set for the first `samplerUnit`. 
Here's how i set up the graph:

```
AudioComponentDescription MixerUnitDescription;
MixerUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
MixerUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer;
MixerUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
MixerUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
MixerUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

AudioComponentDescription cd = {};
cd.componentManufacturer     = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice; // type - music device
cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Sampler; // sub type - sampler to convert our MIDI

result = NewAUGraph (&_processingGraph);
result = AUGraphAddNode(self.processingGraph, &MixerUnitDescription, &mixerNode);

result = AUGraphAddNode (self.processingGraph, &cd, &samplerNode);

result = AUGraphAddNode (self.processingGraph, &cd, &samplerNode2);

cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;  // Output
cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;  // Output to speakers

result = AUGraphAddNode (self.processingGraph, &cd, &ioNode);
result = AUGraphOpen (self.processingGraph);

result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput (self.processingGraph, samplerNode, 0, mixerNode, 0);
result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput (self.processingGraph, samplerNode2, 0, mixerNode, 1);

result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput (self.processingGraph, mixerNode, 0, ioNode, 0);
result = AUGraphNodeInfo (self.processingGraph, samplerNode, 0, &_samplerUnit);
result = AUGraphNodeInfo (self.processingGraph, samplerNode2, 0, &_samplerUnit2);
result = AUGraphNodeInfo (self.processingGraph, ioNode, 0, &_ioUnit);
```

This is the example method from Apple Developer pages which i modified to assign a soundfont to a specific `samplerUnit`:

```
-(OSStatus) loadFromDLSOrSoundFont: (NSURL *)bankURL withPatch: (int)presetNumber withAudioUnit:(AudioUnit)auUnit{

OSStatus result = noErr;

// fill out a bank preset data structure
AUSamplerBankPresetData bpdata;
bpdata.bankURL  = (__bridge CFURLRef) bankURL;
bpdata.bankMSB  = kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB;
bpdata.bankLSB  = kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB;
bpdata.presetID = (UInt8) presetNumber;

// set the kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank property
result = AudioUnitSetProperty(auUnit,
                          kAUSamplerProperty_LoadPresetFromBank,
                          kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                          0,
                          &bpdata,
                          sizeof(bpdata));

// check for errors
NSCAssert (result == noErr,
       @"Unable to set the preset property on the Sampler. Error code:%d '%.4s'",
       (int) result,
       (const char *)&result);

return result;
}
```

Then i did this twice to get each track into `musicSequence`:

```
if(MusicSequenceFileLoad(tmpSequence, (__bridge CFURLRef)midiFileURL, 0, 0 != noErr)) 
{
    [NSException raise:@"play" format:@"Can't load MusicSequence"];
}


MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(tmpSequence, 0, &tmpTrack);
MusicSequenceNewTrack(musicSequence, &track);
MusicTimeStamp trackLen = 0;
UInt32 trackLenLen = sizeof(trackLen);
MusicTrackGetProperty(tmpTrack, kSequenceTrackProperty_TrackLength, &trackLen, &trackLenLen);
MusicTrackCopyInsert(tmpTrack, 0, trackLenLen, track, 0);
```

And finally:

```
MusicTrackSetDestNode(track, samplerNode);
MusicTrackSetDestNode(track2, samplerNode2);
```

But this won't assign the the soundfont to the `samplerUnit2`:

```
[self loadFromDLSOrSoundFont: (NSURL *)presetURL2 withPatch: (int)0 withAudioUnit:self.samplerUnit2];
```

Assigning to `samplerUnit` works fine. Any ideas what i'm missing here?

Comment: It's a little hard to follow all that code in a web page but I didn't see anything glaring - except I didn't see where you define the number of mixer inputs. You need to do this (see my answer edit). Also CAShow(graph) is a great function to display the graph + connections. Can also be used for sequences and tracks: CAShow(sequence). I know assigning unique AUSampler to tracks works - have done it for 10+ tracks in one app in dev.

Comment: many thanks for your help so far. i set the bus count as you said, but that didn't change anything. 
the sequnce graph says 2 tracks, which is right. the connections graph seems right to me:

AudioUnitGraph 0x3D0A000:

  Member Nodes:

 node 1: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl'       

 node 2: 'aumu' 'samp' 'appl'       

 node 3: 'aumu' 'samp' 'appl'          

 node 4: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl'         
  Connections:
 node   2 bus   0 => node   1 bus   0 ;     
 node   3 bus   0 => node   1 bus   1 ;      
 node   1 bus   0 => node   4 bus   0 ;

Comment: A bit hard to see without formatting but it *looks* like its hooked up right. (fwiw- I like to add nodes to the graph from the lowest functional level up so it's a bit more coherent to read the connections and catch any errors: RemoteIO, Mixer, then all the AUSamplers.) If one sampler is working on a track, maybe see if you can get sampler2 to work on the same track (i.e. are both samplers ok). Then both are tracks ok, etc. (process of elimination). Oh - maybe just my quirk but I set up the AUSamplers (loaded fonts, etc) before adding them. Don't know if that matters.

Comment: But how can i know for sure which sampler is working on which track? It seems to me that samplerUnit2 isnt't used at all. Are there any other methods (like CAShow()) for debugging? And sorry for the non-formatted graphs, i can't prevent that in the comments section.

Comment: Does samplerUnit2 use a different *sounding* sound font? (so you can tell if the code is working). Don't know of other debugging methods.

Comment: Yes, they are different. I can tell, because right now i'm working only with the second track (the first is not copied to the sequence) and trying to load the sf2 to the samplerUnit2. It just plays the midi with the default xcode soundfont. when i assign the soundfont to samplerUnit, track2 plays with the loaded soundfont. Could you take a look at it, if i sent you the .m file (or the whole project, there is not much more yet). Thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: Put it online somewhere, if you can, and I'll give it a look.

Comment: So here's the project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14111871/MidiTest%202.zip ...very much appreciated

Comment: I took a look and didn't see anything glaring - seemed like reusing the tmpSequence was causing problems so I made a second one. Same for tmpTrack. Your midi files and sound fonts seem pretty similar so it was hard to hear/know what was going on. Substituted a different midi and sf2 just for diagnostics but I ran out of time to test it (deadline looms). That's how I'd go - try to isolate and test that things are being created as expected, etc.

Comment: I did as you said and created tmpSequence2 and tmpTrack2. Now i can see even better that [self loadFromDLSOrSoundFont: (NSURL *)presetURL2 withPatch: (int)0 withAudioUnit:self.samplerUnit2]; won't assign the soundfont: it won't even load the default soundfont now, all i hear is the rhythm but with a popping sound.

Comment: So i found the solution to the soundfont assignment problem:
it only works if you do MusicSequenceSetAUGraph(musicSequence, _processingGraph); first, and then MusicTrackSetDestNode(track, samplerNode); MusicTrackSetDestNode(track2, samplerNode2);

Comment: I am using MixerHost for audio mixing. I have successfully write output file on disk but that file doesn't having different volume for different audio file. Will you please let me know, how to achieve that? As, I am new to audio tool box, I am not getting how to do that

Comment: You can adjust the volume with AudioUnitSetParameter, if you are using AudioUnits. But Audiotoolbox is a different thing than the stuff discussed here. Maybe you should start a new thread.