# How to change from one musicSequence to another without time delay

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-audio, coremidi

I'm playing a MIDI sequence via `MusicPlayer` which I loaded from a MIDI file and I want to change the sequence to another while playback. 
When I try this:

```
 MusicPlayerSetSequence(_player, sequence);
 MusicSequenceSetAUGraph(sequence, _processingGraph);
```

it stops the playback. So I start it back again and set the time with

```
MusicPlayerSetTime(_player, currentTime);
```

so it plays again where the previous sequence stopped, but there is a little delay.
I've tried to add the time interval to `currentTime`, which I got by obtaining the time before stopping and after starting again. But there is still a delay.

I was wondering if there is an alternative to stopping -> changing sequence -> starting again.

Comment: Hey - did you give up on the combining tracks approach? I finally found some time to get it working. Your files were a bit dodgey - not sure why. Here's an example with one of your midi files/sf2 + a random midi/sf2 I had around (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34715839/MusicPlayerTracksFromFiles.zip) - Cheers

Comment: Oh - there is a bug in that file when setting track loops: the `trackLen` value used is from the sourceTrack. This value should be recalculated from the destination track before setting the loop length. Also, discovered that the weirdness with the simpletest.mid file was due to its having 2 tracks - first one being empty - so copying that track == silence.

Comment: No i didn't, i've found the solution for myself and made another answer there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706042). but thanks anyways, i'm sure your code will help me optimize mine. I'm still trying to figure out how you are looping the sequence, because it's not looping at the right time. i do -  `if (time >=trackLen) MusicPlayerSetTime(_player, 0);`

Comment: Never mind, i got it figured out: you set the property `kSequenceTrackProperty_LoopInfo`. But that won't work for me, because the midi lengths are always something like 3.89 or 5.92, so i actually do `if (time >=ceil(trackLen))`

Comment: So setting the track nodes only works after setting the AUGraph for the sequence - makes sense. @looping - you probably discovered this but each track loops independently. Not a problem if all tracks are the same length but things can get out of sync if they are not. Using an NSTimer on the longest track works - sounds like you are doing that. - Cheers.

Comment: Yes, thanks. So any idea on this question? Today instead of changing the sequence, i tread to clear the tracks and add the tracks from the other sequence. That won't work either, because i still have to update the graph. The only thing i will try now is to get all tracks in one sequence and mute out the tracks which originilly belonged to the other sequence.

Comment: You should be able to add/remove tracks on the fly without significant lag - at least that is what I've found (though my stuff is @ generating new tracks through code, etc.). Changing the sequence is a bigger operation. Updating the graph (adding/removing AUSamplers) should also work fine. Just call that updateGraph function after you have made changes. Anyway - I struggled a lot with the MusicPlayer and docs are "minimalist" - but it does work very well. Assume your app is @ downloading .mid files to combine on the fly (if not, much easier to prep it all beforehand).

Comment: I'm sure adding and removing tracks wont cause lags, but i still have to update the graph which will stop the musicplayer. and i cant get to play at the exact time where it should. i'm trying `currentTime = currentTime - timeInterval*tempo/60` and then `MusicPlayerSetTime(_player, currentTime);`but i can hear that it's not starting where it should be.

Comment: i figured out my bug, and it's a silly one: i started the player and set the time afterwards. thx anyways for your help

Comment: glad you got it working! Cheers-

Comment: did you have problems updating the graph too many times. after changing the sequence for the 16th time, one of the sampler nodes mutes and after 17th the second, so i have no sound at all.

Comment: Are you disconnecting unused AUSamplers from the mixer and reusing the newly available mixer inputs? That code example I posted is set up for only 16 channels (that might be the max # - I forget what the docs specify). The vector + routines in there is for managing the available mixer inputs. Also, you don't have to stop and restart the graph - just update it (you may be doing it this way already).

Comment: i dont know if its internally disconnecting the samplers. all i do is set a new musicSequence. also with your project i tried to ceil(trackLen) because my midis are all like 8.84 or 3.93 beats long (i extracted them from an fl studio file). but when i do this, the looping doesnt start. i cant figure out why. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
MusicPlayerSetSequence(_player, sequence);
MusicSequenceSetAUGraph(sequence, _processingGraph);
```

will still cause the player to stop, it is still possible to hear a little break.
So instead of updating the `musicSequence`, i went ahead and changed the content of the tracks instead, which won't cause any breaks:

```
MusicTrack currentTrack;
MusicTrack currentTrack2;
MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(musicSequence, 0, &currentTrack);
MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(musicSequence, 1, &currentTrack2);
MusicTrackClear(currentTrack, 0, _trackLen);
MusicTrackClear(currentTrack2, 0, _trackLen);

MusicSequence tmpSequence;
switch (number) {
    case 0:
        tmpSequence = musicSequence1;
        break;
    case 1:
        tmpSequence = musicSequence2;
        break;
    case 2:
        tmpSequence = musicSequence3;
        break;
    case 3:
        tmpSequence = musicSequence4;
        break;

    default:
        tmpSequence = musicSequence1;
        break;
}

MusicTrack tmpTrack;
MusicTrack tmpTrack2;
MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(tmpSequence, 0, &tmpTrack);
MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(tmpSequence, 1, &tmpTrack2);
MusicTimeStamp trackLen = 0;
UInt32 trackLenLenLen = sizeof(trackLen);
MusicTrackGetProperty(tmpTrack, kSequenceTrackProperty_TrackLength, &trackLen, &trackLenLenLen);
_trackLen = trackLen;
MusicTrackCopyInsert(tmpTrack, 0, _trackLen, currentTrack, 0);
MusicTrackCopyInsert(tmpTrack2, 0, _trackLen, currentTrack2, 0);
```

No disconnection of nodes, no updating the graph, no stopping the player.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to manage the AUSamplers if you are adding and removing tracks or switching sequences. It probably is cleaner to dispose of the AUSampler and create a new one for each new track but it is also possible to 'recycle' AUSamplers but that means you will need to keep track of them.

Managing AUSamplers means that when you are no longer using an instance of one (for example if you delete or replace a MusicTrack), you need to disconnect it from the AUMixer instance, remove it from the AUGraph instance, and then update the AUGraph.

There are lots of ways to handle all this. For convenience in keeping track of AUSampler instances' bus number, sound font loaded and some other stuff, I use a subClass of NSObject named `SamplerAudioUnit`to contain all the needed properties and methods. Same for MusicTracks - I have a `Track` class - but this may not be needed in your project.

The gist though is that AUSamplers need to be managed for performance and memory. If an instance is no longer being used it should be removed and the AUMixer bus input freed up.

BTW - I check the docs and there is apparently no technical limit to the number of mixer busses - but the number does need to be specified.

```
// this is not cut and paste code - just an example of managing the AUSampler instance

- (OSStatus)deleteTrack:(Track*) trackObj
{
    OSStatus result = noErr;

    // turn off MP if playing
    BOOL MPstate = [self isPlaying];
    if (MPstate){
        MusicPlayerStop(player);
    }

    //-disconnect node from mixer + update list of mixer buses
    SamplerAudioUnit * samplerObj = trackObj.sampler;
    UInt32 busNumber = samplerObj.busNumber;

    result = AUGraphDisconnectNodeInput(graph, mixerNode, busNumber);
    if (result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphDisconnectNodeInput" withStatus: result];}

     [self clearMixerBusState: busNumber]; // routine that keeps track of available busses

    result = MusicSequenceDisposeTrack(sequence, trackObj.track);
    if (result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"MusicSequenceDisposeTrack" withStatus: result];}

    // remove AUSampler node
    result = AUGraphRemoveNode(graph, samplerObj.samplerNode);
    if (result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphRemoveNode" withStatus: result];}

    result = AUGraphUpdate(graph, NULL);
    if (result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphUpdate" withStatus: result];}
    samplerObj = nil;
    trackObj = nil;

    if (MPstate){
        MusicPlayerStart(player);
    }

    //    CAShow(graph);
    //    CAShow(sequence);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Disconnecting, removing and creating a new node solved the problem. Thank you very much.